# Question related to groups.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $a_i \in G$ for all $ n \in N$.

1. Prove that $(a_1a_2a_3)^{-1} = a_3^{-1}a_2^{-1}a_1^{-1}$

My Solution: $(a_1a_2a_3)^{-1}$ = $(a_1a_2)^{-1}(a_3)^{-1}$ = $a_1^{-1}a_2^{-1}a_3^{-1}$

(Now as only Abelian groups are commutative then how can the order change in the answer. Either that or I'm missing something.)

Comment: Distributivity properties only necessary hold in abelian groups, too (ie. $(ab)^c=a^cb^c$)

Comment: No, it doesn't work that way, there is no rule justifying the operations that you do... You have to show that $a_3^{-1}a_2^{-1}a_1^{-1}$ is the _inverse_ of $a_1a_2a_3$. This means you must show that their product equals the identity element...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my question. Missed such a simple thing.

$(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Through this one is able to solve the question.

$(abc)^{-1} = [(ab)(c)]^{-1} = (c)^{-1}(ab)^{-1} = c^{-1}b^{-1}a^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

$a_1 a_2 a_3 a_3^{-1} a_2^{-1}a_1^{-1}=1$ shows the result by definition.